# VBA Mismatch errors, writing a formula

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I need some help. I need help with the mismatch error I get with setting Plan="LogInfo[PLAN]"  and subsequently. Also need help writing a formula I wrote in excel in VBA format.

The lookup would be from LogInfo to Design, to display values from the Design Table to LogInfo in user selected cells.

Plan needs to match Plan, Soils Report needs to match Soils Report, and the em and ym values all need to match to display design, bw, bd.

```
Sub WorkInProgress()

'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Plan As Range, Soils As Range, emC As Range, emE As Range, ymC As Range, ymE As Range               'dims for LogInfo Table/Worksheet
    Dim Plan1 As Range, Soils1 As Range, emC1 As Range, emE1 As Range, ymC1 As Range, _
    ymE1 As Range, design As Range, bw As Range, bd As Range                                                'dims for Design Table/Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("LogInfo")                   ' Table in this worksheet is also called "LogInfo"
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Design")                   ' Table in this worksheet is called "Design"
    
    Set Plan = "LogInfo[PLAN]"                          ' Col Header is called PLAN within the table
    Set Plan1 = "Design[PLAN]"                          ' Col Header is called PLAN within the table
    Set Soils = "LogInfo[SOILS REPORT]"                 ' Col Header is called SOILS REPORT within the table
    Set Soils1 = "Design[SOILS REPORT]"                 ' Col Header is called SOILS REPORT within the table
    Set emC = "LogInfo[em CENTER]"                      ' Col Header is called em CENTER within the table
    Set emC1 = "Design[em CENTER]"                      ' Col Header is called em CENTER within the table
    Set emE = "LogInfo[em EDGE]"                        ' Col Header is called em EDGE within the table
    Set emE1 = "Design[em EDGE]"                        ' Col Header is called em EDGE within the table
    Set ymC = "LogInfo[ym CENTER]"                      ' Col Header is called ym CENTER within the table
    Set ymC1 = "Design[ym CENTER]"                      ' Col Header is called ym CENTER within the table
    Set ymE = "LogInfo[ym EDGE]"                        ' Col Header is called ym EDGE within the table
    Set ymE1 = "Design[ym EDGE]"                        ' Col Header is called ym EDGE within the table
    Set design = "Design[Design]"                       ' Col Header is called Design within the table
    Set bw = "Design[BW]"                               ' Col Header is called BW within the table
    Set bd = "Design[BD]"                               ' Col Header is called BD within the table

    If Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Only select the cells you want numbered"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each c In Selection
        If Not c.Rows.Hidden Then
            c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup()
            'I need help writing the formula above to match this
            '"=XLOOKUP(1,(Design!C[2]=[@PLAN]) * (Design!C[3]=[@[SOILS REPORT]]),Design!C[-4],""Needs To Be Designed"",0)"
            '
            '
            '
            '
        Else
            c.Clear
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim LogInfo As ListObject`, `Set LogInfo = ws.ListObjects("LogInfo")`, then `Set Plan = LogInfo.ListColumns("PLAN").DataBodyRange`. Or `Set Plan = Range("LogInfo[PLAN]")`. Currently the right-hand side is just a `String`, hence the type mismatch.

Comment: c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(1, Range("B1:B3"), Range("C1:C3"), "Needs To Be Designed",0)

It is easier to set the range you want, or if is a named range or a table the name of the column itself